# postgresql regexp_replace with character '

Tags: postgresql, replace

I have a table in which some variables are with the characters' and a space in front of the data, eg

```
name   | code 
manoel | '02
```

the code should be 4 digits thereby 0002 
 
because the damn apostrophe'm having some difficulties, someone would have some solution?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET yourcol=replace('yourcol', ' ''', '00')`

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are in the format you stated (' '02) then this query will replace all apostrophes with '00' from your column and remove any space in the beginning if they exist.

```
UPDATE table SET code = TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(code, chr(39),'00')
```

The problem with using

```
UPDATE table SET yourcol=replace('yourcol', ' ''', '00')
```

is that it will replace only columns with a space and a comma, however, if there is no space, it will not replace the apostrophes. The query will work only if you are 100% all the unwanted formatted columns are in that format, otherwise use the first query.